# Distributive Law in Boolean Algebra problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

Im practicing boolean algebra on the following problem

```
(A+B)(¬A+¬B)
```

In my textbook they apply the distributive property to get

```
A(¬A+¬B)+B(¬A+¬B)
```

Im not quite sure how this is being applied and would appreciate some clarification.

I know the distributive property is defined as followed

```
A(B+C)=(AB)+(AC)
```

But in our problem we have (A+B)(¬A+¬B) not (AB)+(AC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the distributive property is defined as followed
>
> ```
> A(B+C)=(AB)+(AC)
> ```

It is also the case that conjunction is commutative, so

```
 (A+B)(¬A+¬B) = (¬A+¬B)(A+B)          Commute
              = (¬A+¬B)A+(¬A+¬B)B     Distribute
              = A(¬A+¬B)+B(¬A+¬B)     Commute
```

Answer (score 0):

They implicitly assumed $C=A'+B'$, and so
$$(A+B)(A'+B')=(A+B)C$$$$=AC+BC=A(A'+B')+B(A'+B')$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)